# How to have gradient over image?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, next.js, material-ui

Ok i wanna have a gradient on images.
This is my implemention

```js
import Image from 'next/image'
import Box from 'mui/material/Box'
import PlayIcon from './PlayIcon.tsx'

        <Box
          sx={{
            display:'flex',
            alignItems:'center',
            justifyContent:'center',
            position: 'relative',
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%',
            backgroundImage: `linear-gradient(180deg, ${image?.data.gradient.colorOne}, ${image?.data.gradient.colorTwo})`,
          }}
        >
          <Image
            src={image.data.url}
            width={imgWidth}
            height={'80px'}
          />
          {image?.data.playButton && <PlayIcon />} // NOTICE: HAVE A ABOSULTE POSITION BECAUSE ICON SHOULD BE ON CENTER OF IMAGE
        </Box>
```

I tried everything but the gradient is under image. How can i fix this ?
I would really appreciate some help

Answer (score -3):

try to set a z-index
link to guide : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/z-index